# What is the default memory and cpu resource allocated to a pod by kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

What is the default cpu and memory allocated to a Pod in a custom (not default) namespace when NO limit OR request is specified?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you have no LimitRange - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/_print/#create-a-limitrange-and-a-pod - or any other restrictions, then none

Answer (score 2):

I think [Kubernetes Limit Ranges](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/) docs answers your question

> *"By default, containers run with **unbounded** compute resources on a Kubernetes cluster..."*

Comment: And on the flipside, no requests are treated like 0s, so it allows unlimited packing up to the max pods per node (default 110).

Comment: Meaning the CPU on the node the pod is running on minus traffic from other pods on the node? Or the CPU available to all nodes in the cluster?

Comment: Pods are racing over resources, so let's say you have a Node with 2-Cpu and 8GB-Memory. Theoretically, the computing power of the node is available to all the pods. This also means that your pods can cause the Node to crash if there's an overload - consuming more than 2-Cpu and 8GB-Memory at the same time. I hope that answers your question